# Align 4 sets of side-by-side barplots in powerpoint so that bars are perfectly aligned in every way

Tags: automation, microsoft-powerpoint, alignment

I'm not asking for the align feature because it's not perfect enough, but I'm wondering whether there's a automated way to align 4 sets of side-by-side barplots in powerpoint without clicking and draging.  Here's an example made in different software R
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify "perfectly aligned in every way"?  What are the applicable ways?  Bars within the graph?  Grid lines from graph to graph?

Comment: Both them you mentioend

Comment: "....the align feature because it's not perfect enough..." what does that mean? What are you doing, exactly? what is the result? how does it differ from the expected result? Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1458887/edit) to let us know

Comment: A screen shot of the results of a normal Align, with callouts indicating where you feel the problems are would help us understand what you need.

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is possible in PowerPoint using the Smart-Art tools. W.r.t to the output you want, you have 2 options to choose from "**Picture caption list**" or "**Picture Grid**" (highlighted in screenshot below using double-arrow)

You can find this in the insert tab in the ribbon. Please see the sample screenshot below.

[image: Auto-Align images]